# How to map master detail on hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

[image]

I can not change the db schema and this is what I got so far:

```
public class User{
  @Id
  private String userId;
  @OneToMany
  @JoinTable(
       name = "user_invoice",
       joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name="user_id"),
       inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "invoice_id")
  )
  private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;
}

public class InvoiceItem{
  @Id
  private String invoiceId;
  private String invoiceItemId;
}
```

This configuration does not allow invoice_id to be duplicated on invoice_item table(it should since I can have multiple items on a given invoice)
If I make invoice_item_id composite pk I would need to add an extra column on user_invoice table which I can not.
How can I map this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could split up the many-to-many association into two one-to-many associations and an entity for the join table. You can map it like this:

```java
public class User{
  @Id
  private String userId;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
  private List<Invoice> invoices;
}
@Table(name = "user_invoice")
public class Invoice{
  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
  private User user;
  @Id
  private String invoiceId;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "invoice")
  private List<InvoiceItem> invoiceItems;
}

public class InvoiceItem{
  @Id
  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  private Invoice invoice;
  @Id
  private String invoiceItemId;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @Christian-beikon, I notice your solution adds invoice entity so do you think isnt possible with only 2 entity? was the tables designed wrongly?

Comment: Yeah the table was designed wrongly. If you want to use a `@ManyToMany` association you must mention the full primary key in the join table.

Comment: I cant see the @ManyToMany relationship here, could you explain it?

Comment: I updated the answer and added a little explanation

Comment: I see...so is there no way to make a many-to-many relationship without copying the full primary key?

Comment: A many-to-many association is by definition modeled by a putting the unique keys from both sides into a join table. The database model you are having does not model a many-to-many association.